# Proving with diagonal lemma

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to solve a problem, using the diagonal lemma (I know how to solve it with a different method).

For some function  f ∈ N → (N → N) I need to find a set  E ⊆ N → N, with cardinality  |E| = ℵ, such that  E ∩ Imf =  ∅.

I thought about something like g(n) = (f(n))(n) + k, k∈N. But then |E| = ℵ0, which is not good enough.

any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is "$\aleph$"? Do you mean "$\aleph_1$"? Or $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: for any $n$, as long as $g(n)=(f(n))(n)+k$ for $k$ positive, $g\not=f$. *So you have some freedom in picking $k$*. In particular, it can be a different $k$ for different $n$s! Do you see a way, given an infinite sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of zeroes and ones (there's continuum many of these), to come up with a sequence $(k_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of positive integers ("things to add") based on that sequence? Do you see how to use this to define such an $E$, and prove that it has the desired properties?

Comment: Thank you, but I still dont understand how to connect k to a binary sequence...

Comment: @user401516 Think about one particular example of such a $g$: $g(0)=(f(0))(0)+1$, $g(1)=(f(1))(1)+2$, $g(2)=(f(2))(2)+1$, $g(3)=(f(3))(3)+1$, . . . Do you see how there's a sequence of "things to add" associated to this $g$? Do you see how to go from here?

Comment: I got it! thanks a lot. There are simply ℵ ways to "add things" (by adding the fitting digit in any sequence of 1 and 2. Do you think you can help me formalize it a little? sounds very unformal when i put it this way.

Comment: @user401516 Try to describe a specific way to take a sequence of $0$s and $1$s and get a relevant $g$. HINT: suppose the $17$th entry of the sequence is $1$. What should $g(17)$ be? What about if the $17$th entry is $0$?

Comment: The problem is for each of these g's, i need to add k that describes the diggit of a different sequence... cant find a way to write it explicitly

Comment: @user401516 If $h$ is a function assigning to each $k$ a "thing to add" $h(k)$, then $g$ can be written as $$g(k)=(f(k))(k)+h(k).$$ Do you see why? Now it's enough to define $h$ in terms of the infinite binary sequence you're given.