# Using the diagonal of Cantor

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm given a function $g:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and I need to find a set $A$ whose cardinality equals to the cardinality of the continuum and $ A  \cap g[N] = \emptyset$

I don't really know how to start with solving this problem. I'd really like some hints/clues rather than an answer. Thank you! :)

Comment: what does $g: \mathbb{N} \to (\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N})$ mean?

Comment: @DavidBowman hey David! It's a function from N (the naturals) to the set N->N (Set of the functions from N to N)

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes! Gah, I forgot to mention that. sorry!

Comment: @QthePlatypus What do you mean by that?

Comment: This is identical to the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076354/proving-with-diagonal-lemma.

Comment: lola Sorry my hint doesn't make sense after your clarification you have @henningMakolm.  However to make up I'll give two hints.

Every function $ \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ can be encoded in a real.
There are noncomputable real numbers.

Comment: @QthePlatypus: That doesn't help either; nobody promised that $g$ is computable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes it would be better to point out that there are more real numbers then their are natural numbers.

You are right that nobody promised that g is computable but in that case you can use g as an oracle that just gives you a countable infinity of new reals.  That said it is less useful to the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want $A$ to be a subset of $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, too; otherwise there is no fun at all here.

**Hint** as requested: Do you know how to use a diagonalization argument to find *one* function that is not in the range of $g$?

Can you think of a way to create $2^{\mathbb N}$ different version of that diagonalization argument, such that you're sure they all create *different* functions outside the range of $g$?

---

As an alternative, **cheat:** If you know enough basic cardinal arithmetic, just set $A = (\mathbb N\to\mathbb N)\setminus g(\mathbb N)$ and argue that this must be uncountable because $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is, and $g(\mathbb N)$ is at most countable.

Comment: Thank you so much Henning! But I'm asked to specifically use the diagonal of cantor. I'm still thinking of a way to work with your first hint =)

Comment: I think I got you! I can  fix a function 'f' which receives a natural number 'n' and outputs (g(n))(n) + k
while k can change and it depends on the input...is there a way to define A mathematically?
forgot to mention that k belongs to the set {1,2}

Comment: @Lola: Yes, that's a workable idea. I suppose you mean something like $g(n)(n)+k(n)$ where $k\in \mathbb N\to\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank you so much for the help :) From here it wouldn't be a problem to show that everything works

Answer (score 1):

I guess, $A$ is supposed to be $\subseteq \Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ (the set of functions $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$), else we could answer an arbitrary continuum big set.

**Hints:**

1. Given $B\subseteq \Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$, what is the biggest subset $A\subseteq \Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ with $B\cap A=\emptyset$?
2. What can be the cardinality of $B:=g[\Bbb N]$?
3. What is the cardinality of $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$?
4. Continuum minus countable?